# Smooth gradient in FF and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, gradient, smoothing

I have these lines for horizontal gradient from #191919 to transparent generated by http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/, but in FireFox 29 and IE 8 it doesnt smooth. And it's on background #191919. (Color-depth problem?)
If it won't to be a fix, then how it block for this browsers? Thank You.

```
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: #191919;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(25,25,25,1) 0%, rgba(25,25,25,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(25,25,25,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(25,25,25,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(25,25,25,1) 0%,rgba(25,25,25,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(25,25,25,1) 0%,rgba(25,25,25,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(25,25,25,1) 0%,rgba(25,25,25,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(25,25,25,1) 0%,rgba(25,25,25,0) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#191919', endColorstr='#19191900',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQ33C/) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for IE 8:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#191919', endColorstr='#191919',GradientType=1 )"; /* IE8 */
```

You will have to include this too:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#191919', endColorstr='#19191900',GradientType=1 );
```

Also you had two extra zero's after `#191919`